# how to solve $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-x{\tau}} \cdot x\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I took ${-x^2-x{\tau}} = k $ on differentiating it $dk=(-2x-\tau)dx$ but this substitution doesn't work how can i proceed further .

Comment: "Complete the square" in the exponent and _then_ apply a change of variables to get an integrand that has $-y^2$ in the exponent.

Comment: all right i got that,thanks

Comment: As explained in the duplicate, complete the square in the exponent. I don't believe the difference between the two questions is enough to not make them duplicates.

Comment: because we need some addidtional techniques (IPB or Feynman's trick) it's not obvious to me that this is a duplicate to this particular question

Comment: i don't know about IPB or Feynman's trick

Comment: Intgeration by Parts (=IPB), differentiating under the integral sign (=Feynman's Trick)

Answer (score 4):

complete the square:

$-x^2-\tau x=-x^2-\tau x-\frac{\tau^2}{4}+\frac{\tau^2}{4}=-(x+\frac{\tau}{2})+\frac{\tau^2}{4}$

So your integral equals:

$$
-\partial_{\tau}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^
{-x^2-x\tau}\right]=-\partial_{\tau}\left[e^{\frac{\tau^2}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x+\frac{\tau}{2})^2}dx \right]=-\partial_{\tau}e^{\frac{\tau^2}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: not quite, you missed the "times" $x$, but I guess you can handle that via partial integration

Comment: sorry i totally missed the x, but i have corrected it now...

Comment: oh, nice idea to represent the integral as the derivative!

Comment: what is $\partial_\tau$

Comment: *Can you take it from here?* - Why ? You're too tired to finish the job yourself ? :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian, Yes indeed ;-)

Comment: @Akashaero $\partial_{\tau}$ means differentiate with respect to $\tau$